# Using DictWriter/Reader with csv module in python

Tags: python, csv, select, cell

I want to parse a csv file, looking in Field3 for cells which dont have any "/" in and copy these cells in a output.csv file in a fieldoutput row.

I tried the following code but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
    ", ".join(wrong_fields))

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv

f = open("C:\My\Path\file.csv", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(f,  delimiter=';')
writer = open("C:\My\Path\output.csv",'wb')
output = csv.DictWriter(writer, 'fieldoutput', delimiter=';')

print output

for row in reader:
    if '/' not in row['Field3'] :
        #print row['Field3']
        output.writerow(row)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're specifying the second `DictWriter` parameter correctly. Since the rows you're writing are dictionaries, `DictWriter` needs to know how to order the fields:

> The fieldnames parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the writerow() method are written to the csvfile.

Try changing your DictWriter initialization from this:

```
output = csv.DictWriter(writer, 'fieldoutput', delimiter=';')
```

to this:

```
output = csv.DictWriter(writer, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: Yeah it worked but not exactly as i expected: i got all the rows copied and not only field3). That explain the way i set the parameter with my newbie point of view. I think i need to finish with: output.writerow(row[Field3]) or something.